# Adhesive to connect metal with a coating to plastic that resists mineral oil

Tags: metals, plastic, adhesive, tubing

I have a peristaltic pump that was having some leaks because of connections between the tubing so I decided to replace it all with a single piece of tubing. Upon doing this though, I observed that the tubing on the outlet side of the pump was being forced upwards.

My peristaltic pump comes with a base that is made out of plastic. I want to glue something to the outlet side of the pump that will create some friction on the outside of the tubing keeping it from moving. I have some M20 nuts that are just large enough to fit around tubing and might offer the proper resistance if I can adhere them to the plastic.

However, the metal has a black coating on it that might cause some issues, and I am pumping mineral oil so I need to use some glue that will resist that for prolonged use while the pump is on. I'm fine with the nuts being permanently affixed to the plastic. I was wondering if anyone on this forum has some ideas for glues I can use to do this.

**Update**
Here is a picture of the pump from Amazon. Looks like I got the last one. Anyway, the plastic is the black frame around the cylindrical motor.
[image: pump]

Comment: what kind of plastic? Do you have a picture?

Comment: I don't know the type of plastic. I'll update my post with a picture.

Comment: Ok, you're not talking about the barbed fitting I hope? That's probably PP. You need to be able to get it out to change the peristalic tube when it wears out // the black parts can be anything, tho I would've had them made from PBT, given a choice. It should be easier to glue that PP. Any metal coating can be sanded off where you glue. Prep both surfaces with a little sanding and clean with IPA. Look for an epoxy compatible with your fluids

Comment: ps look closely... if black plastic is machined in small volume it may be POM/acetal/delrin type , i.e. formaldehyde polymer. i.e. reactive (good for glue). Nylon also possible, cheap choice but also easy to glue. PP would be softer, unlikely IMO. hard to glue. If molded and designed from a bigger company there may be material indication on an inside surface

Comment: No. As I mentioned, I replaced the piece of tubing with an entire length of larger tubing. I'm referring to the black base housing the motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3M makes some unbelieveably strong "doublesticky" indoor/outdoor elastomeric tape that is used to do things like attach chrome trim to the outsides of car bodies. Home Depot sells it in rolls and squares; I do not know if it is mineral oil-resistant but it is worth a try.

Comment: I'll check it out online to see if it is mineral oil resistant. I want to wait and see if there are other answers. In a few days if no one responds I'll select yours.

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-Scotch-1-in-x-1-66-yds-Permanent-Double-Sided-Outdoor-Mounting-Tape-411DC-SF/100575385

Comment: Close. I have used the scotch "Extremely Strong" mounting tape.